# Posting to Facebook with PHP/jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Alright, there are a lot of moving parts here, so I will try to be as thorough as possible.

To start, there is an  tag on my site, which is designated to post a dynamically loaded photo to facebook.

```
<a onclick=\"postToFacebook('"+photoURL+"');\"><img src='facebook-icon.png'/></a>
```

The stripped down javascript function that is called when this link is clicked looks like this:

```
function postToFacebook(photoURL) {
    contentCode += "<div id='overlay-col2'><input type='text' id='facebook-caption-textbox' name='facebook-caption-textbox' class='textbox-wide inactive' value='Caption'/>";
    contentCode += "<textarea id='facebook-message-textarea' name='facebook-message-textarea' class='textarea-wide inactive'>Say something about this photo...</textarea>";
    contentCode += "<a class='overlay-submit-btn' onclick=\"submitFacebookPosting('"+photoURL+"');\">Post to Facebook</a></div>";

    $("#overlay-body-content").empty().html(contentCode);
}
```

What this code does is creates populates an overlay window with a small web form that enables the user to enter in a caption for the photo, as well as a textarea to say a little something about the photo.  As you can see, when they hit the submit link, another javascript function is called: submitFacebookPosting().  That function looks like this:

```
function submitFacebookPosting(photoURL) {
    var photoCaption = $("#facebook-caption-textbox").attr("value");
    var photoMessage = $("#facebook-message-textarea").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'postToFacebook.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({photoURL:photoURL, photoCaption:photoCaption, photoMessage:photoMessage}),
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == "success") {
                alert("Photo has been posted to your Facebook Wall.");
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, there is the file, postToFacebook.php, which is considerably longer.  The contents of that look like this:

```
<?php

    $photoURL = $_POST['photoURL'];
    $caption = $_POST['photoCaption'];
    $message = $_POST['photoMessage'];

    $fbconfig['appid' ] = "--hidden--";
    $fbconfig['secret'] = "--hidden--";
    $fbconfig['baseurl'] = "http://www.jhublerdesign.com/proofStar/dashboard.php";
    $user = null;

    try {
        include_once "facebook.php";
    } catch(Exception $o) {
        error_log($o);
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
        'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();    
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
            'redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
    );

    $logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();


    if ($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "This photo has been posted from ProofStar!", 
                'link'    => $photoURL,
                'picture' => $photoURL,
                'name'    => 'DSC_1234',
                'description'=> $message
            ));
            echo "success";
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
?>
```

So, with all of that said - whenever I submit the form to AJAX, it returns as an error, but does not show me what error it is, and it most certainly does not post to Facebook.

Any ideas what I am missing?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the line **echo "we got here";** right before the last try/catch statement to make sure you are getting this far.

If you get there try the same thing before **echo $e;**.

Comment: Okay, so I tried echoing in a couple of different places, and here's what I've got for you:  if I echo "The user is $user"; right between the two if($user) statements towards the end, I get a "The User is 0", which tells me that it is not picking up the user.  I also tried doing your suggestion and putting a "we got here" echo just before the try/catch and it didn't make it.

Comment: Additionally - this script is set up on a page that you have to log into to access.  Will that make any difference?  In my Facebook App settings, I have the app url as "dashboard.php", instead of "index.php".  Index.php is the login page, and upon successful login, you are taken to dashboard.php.  Will that affect anything?

Comment: Using **dashbord.php** should be OK as long as it is in your **App Domain** and you include the JavaScript SDK on that page. Maybe check your **App ID** and **Secret**?

Comment: App ID & Secret are correct.  It turns out that in my dashboard.php, I did not have the Javascript SDK on that page.  To remedy this, I added the following line into head of dashboard.php: <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>.  How do i check that dashboard.php is in my App Domain?

Comment: The  App Domain is just your domain name -- it is set in Basic Settings. IOW, both pages should be hosted by the same domain name (yours are) and that domain name is specified in your *App Settings*. I don't think the *App Domain* is your problem.